# How to retrieve the parent control and its children controls - Winforms C# 2

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I want to retrieve controls of a form. To do this :

```
internal static IEnumerable<Control> EnumereTousControle(Control controleParent)
{
    foreach (Control subControl in controleParent.Controls)
    {
        yield return subControl;

        foreach (Control c in EnumereTousControle(subControl))
            yield return c;
    }
}
```

It works fine, all children of the parent control are retrieved. But I need this method returns the parent control too. I tried this but it don't works (because the method is recursive) :

```
internal static IEnumerable<Control> EnumereAllControls(Control parentControl)
{
    yield return parentControl; // does not work

    foreach (Control subControl in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        yield return subControl;

        foreach (Control c in EnumereAllControls(subControl))
            yield return c;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thnk you just had one line too many, try this:

```
internal static IEnumerable<Control> EnumereAllControls(Control parentControl)
{
    yield return parentControl;

    foreach (Control subControl in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in EnumereAllControls(subControl))
            yield return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    internal static IEnumerable<Control> EnumereTousControle(Control controleParent) {
        yield return controleParent;
        foreach (Control ctl in controleParent.Controls) {
            foreach (Control child in EnumereTousControle(ctl)) 
                yield return child;
        }
    }
```

Well, same thing minus the extra yield you got.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the parent control to the result from outside the method if that is not a constraint.